# Cookie set by website A is visible in chrome dev tools to website B

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I have website A (a.com) which uses API (myapi.com) and that API, on login request, sets the cookie to identify the user (set-cookie: user=123; domain=myapi.com; secure; samesite=none). As expected, I see that cookie in Chrome Dev Tools > Application > Cookies > https://a.com > Name: user and this cookie is sent then in every following request to API (myapi.com) service, so up until now everything works like I think it should work.

But now comes weird part, I have second website B (b.org) (hosted on completely separate domain) which also uses API (myapi.com) service, but this time without login request, it executes only public endpoints, now when I will open B (b.org) in same browser I previously signed in to A (a.com), in Chrone Dev Tools > Application > Cookies > https://b.org I see the user cookie, this cookie is not sent to API (myapi.com), but I can see it in Dev Tools, and I wonder why is that? Isn't it a bug? Luckily that cookie is not sent to the API (myapi.com) from B (b.org) website, but it is still there. I see this in chrome and brave.

Comment: This sounds like http://crbug.com/1368918

Comment: Indeed it looks like answer to my question, thanks for this